# Proving that a process is class DL

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_{t})$
  be a stochastic process with $X_{t}\sim\mathcal{N}(\xi_{t},\sigma_{t}^{2})$
  where $\xi_{t}\downarrow0$
  and $\sigma_{t}^{2}\uparrow1/2$.

What would be the most straightforward way of showing that

$\left\{ \mbox{exp}(X_{T}^{2}-T):T\;\mbox{stopping time},\; T\leq t\right\}$

is Uniformly integrable for each $t\geq0$?

That is, that $\mbox{exp}(X_{t}^{2}-t)$ is Class DL.

I've been trying to show that it is bounded in $L^2$ by using that I know the density of the normal distribution. But I have not succeeded in this.

Note: I realize that it's not necessarily a (local) martingale. I'm just trying to familiarize myself with notion of being "Class DL". If someone has another similar looking example - e.g. $(X_t)$ being a Brownian motion - I'm also happy to see that.

Comment: Are you particulary interested in the squared process in the exponent (i.e. $X_T^2$)? The standard example (involving exponentials) are the Doleans-Dade exponentials, that is $\exp(M_t - \langle M \rangle_t)$ for a martingale $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and its quadratic variation $\langle M \rangle$. It is not difficult to prove that this kind of process is uniformly integrable. (E.g. for a Brownian motion, the corresponding process is $\exp (B_t - t/2)$.)

Comment: @saz Yes I'm interested in the squared process. In the Dolean dade case, it is easy to see that it's of the form $\mbox{exp}(B_{t}-t/2)dB_{t}$ and $\mbox{exp}(B_{t}-t/2)$ is in L2 by using the gaussian density. I guess what I was wondering is how one would typically approach a slightly harder problem like the sqaured case. Would the normal strategy be to use chi-square density or is there a better (easier) way?

Comment: @saz E.g.  a good criterion like Novikov's now that we're talking Dolean Dade.